# maven release plugin and multiple projects in separate git repositories with Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin, multi-project, multiple-repositories

I’ve found quite a few hints about the `maven-release-plugin`, multi-module, multi-project, parent POMs, etc. but they all don’t quite fit what I have:

I have several projects (the reduced case is two: `project-common` and `project-impl`) that are *somewhat* separate from each other, and developed in separate git repositories, but usually released together. For this purpose, `project-common/pom.xml` contains:

```
<groupId>de.tarent.example</groupId>
<artifactId>project-common</artifactId>
<version>1.5.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

… and `project-impl/pom.xml` contains:

```
<groupId>de.tarent.example</groupId>
<artifactId>project-impl</artifactId>
<version>1.5.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.tarent.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-common</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

There is *no* parent POM.

The idea here is to *generally* use the version of `project-common` for them all, but be able to occasionally do individual releases of only one project; in those cases, the dependency version would, of course, have to be manually changed, but that’s okay.

Now, we’re using Jenkins’ “Perform Maven Release” to create our releases. (Well, we wish to. The projects were until recently not releasable, so our developers built them by hand, complete with temporary files, unused files, local changes, LDAP passwords in XML configs, editor `.swp` files, etc. – you can see why I was tasked to change this, despite not knowing Java™ *or* Maven *or* Jenkins. Or maybe, because of it.)

The release of `project-common` goes without a hitch, but `project-impl` fails at the very first phase, checking that there are no SNAPSHOT dependencies. Well duh. (There are none except the `project-common` one.) Overriding the `maven-release-plugin` to skip the SNAPSHOT check is impossible. Using a parent POM does not work here either, as these are completely separate repositories and, on occasion, released independently. So, how to do this while retaining the Jenkins and Maven Release comfort?

Continue on to: Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading logs, I figured out that Jenkins invokes Maven like this:

```
mvn -B -f /var/lib/hudson/jobs/project-impl/workspace/pom.xml \
    -DdevelopmentVersion=1.5.1.5-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=1.5.1.4 \
    -Dtag=1.5.1.4 -Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform \
    -DpreparationGoals=clean install -e
```

The `-D` had to be good for something, right? Could I do `${project.version:-${releaseVersion}}` like in shell, I asked a coworker (thanks Umer!), who said, not like that, but `-D` overrides properties.

That stopped me short for a bit: I could not place the version into the property, because the maven-release-plugin only updates the project `<version>` element.

Thankfully, double indirection works. While an ugly hack, and it **will** break if someone does not use Jenkins to release, or if someone uses `-DreleaseVersion` locally, two little changes made those projects releasable:

First, we add a property called `releaseVersion` which defaults to the (dynamically updated) `${project.version}`:

```
<properties>
    <releaseVersion>${project.version}</releaseVersion>
</properties>
```

Then, we change the dependency to use that instead:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.tarent.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-common</artifactId>
        <version>${releaseVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The only other problem I can see with this solution is if some{one,thing} uses the released POM from the Maven repository, as it also contains this indirection (we don’t filter the POMs on release). But it works well, so far.

And if there is a need for `project-impl`, one will just change the `<version>${releaseVersion}</version>` line to `<version>1.5.1.4</version>` manually, just like before (*ceteris paribus*).